# "Natural" labeling of triangles

Tags: category-theory, triangles

The angles of a triangle are (capital) $A,B,C$ and the lengths of the sides are (lower-case) $a,b,c$.

At your mother's knee, you were taught that the side whose length is called (lower-case) $a$ should be **opposite** the angle labeled $A$.

Is it the case that in the sense of category theory or in some other appropriate **precisely definable** sense, this particular way of labeling the sides is "natural" and the other five are not?

Comment: What does natural mean in category theory?

Comment: I assume you mean something more precise than invariance under rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @avid19 : That might be a good question to be posted as a "question". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @LorenoHeer : A rotation in $\mathbb R^n$ would rotate BOTH the angles and the sides.  One could speak of a "rotation" that moves the side labels while leaving the angles as they are, but what would "invariance" be then? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, I meant given a triangle ABC, if one rotates it to say ACB, then the usual assignment sending A to BC is the only assignment invariant under such rotation (eg it sends A to CB which is the same edge)...